# Why Jboss drool rules expiring before timing

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I am facing issue rule is not considering time, date is working fine

```
rule "My Rule"
    no-loop true
    dialect "mvel"
    date-effective "05-JUN-2017 05:00" #after midnight
    date-expires "07-JUL-2017 05:00"   #before 23:59.59 on 6th July

when
   eval ( true )
then
    log.debug( "My rule executed" );
end
```

Comment: What is your setting of the property `drools.dateformat`?

Comment: @laune I haven't specified it must be default

Answer (score 1):

We can find in the code:

```
DEFAULT_FORMAT_MASK = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
```

which is the default if the drools.dateformat property isn't set. Use a String value that is valid according to the specs of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to set the property.

Comment: I have added in property file drools.dateformat=dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm   but this didn't work